# php string variables in gettext (forgot one case scenario)

Tags: php, string, variables, gettext, poedit

I've posted a question yesterday but I just realized that the answer doesn't seem to be working for a certain situation. The post was [php string variables in gettext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349159/php-string-variables-in-gettext/1349209#1349209) and here is what I asked about:

> Hello,
>
> How does gettext translate string
>   variables? It doesn't seem to want to
>   do it.. lets say I have $sentence =
>   "Hello World"; and then I want to echo
>   ($sentence); ... how can I do that so
>   that I can translate what's inside
>   $sentence in Poedit?I can use -> echo
>   sprintf(("%s test"), $sentence) and
>   this will print "Hello World test" in
>   the browser but it will appear as "%s
>   test" in Poedit and I won't get the
>   translated version of Hello World
>   inside of Poedit. So how can I use
>   string variables inside Poedit?
>   Thanks!

This has been solved.

The problem occurs if I want to grab data from an XML file and translate it.

I want to be able to do the following:

```
$foo = $xmlData -> titleText;
```

and then

```
echo _($foo);
```

or something like

```
$finalVar = _($foo);
```

If I look at the php file in the browser I can see the content of $foo on the page but Poedit doesn't pick up the string inside $foo so I can translate it.

(I believe this problem will also occur when translating info within js files)

Thank you for your help,

Simon

Comment: If the strings you want to translate are actually the string in XML file and not the PHP file, you have to run `xgettext` against the XML file to extract the strings to translate, which you then need to translate. If your translation database / `.mo` file contains all the required translations, the code using just `_($foo)` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can't make Poedit understand PHP.

**EDIT**: Have you considered a different approach?

```
if (true) {
    $foo = _('variable holds true');
}

else {
    $foo = _('variable holds false');
}

echo $foo;
```

You can have PHP generated the gettext compatible XML and regarding the database, I believe the best solution is to store the translation in the DB itself, however you can also create a script to dump all the keys and values from the database and use gettext on it.

Comment: I understand that, but your comment doesn't really help me with my problem. Is there a workaround? I could use a language structure for the XML files but I would prefer to solve this issue with gettext somehow... This problem will also occur if I would get data from a database...

Comment: I'm sorry but if I know how to solve your problem I would have answered it. I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Yes I've considered that approach but I was trying to figure out a way to use the XML files I have. I didn't want to generate them, I wanted to use it as a skeleton for things like input fields for categories, meta tags and so on. I think I'm going to just drop XML from the picture or perhaps do what I said before (duplicate the XML files according to the languages). I wish Poedit could compile PHP code, it would be much easier... Thanks for your help.