# php string variables with foreach using gettext

Tags: php, gettext

It seems that the way to make your text echo out using gettext is to use the form:

```
<?php echo _("My text"); ?>
```

Of course, when you are using variables you can't just add quotation marks, since then the variable name would be outputted as a literal, e.g.:

```
<?php echo _("$myText");?>
```

doesn't work.

In a related post, [php string variables in gettext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349159/php-string-variables-in-gettext), the answer seemed to indicate that you just CAN'T use string variables, and that you would need to hardcode the variable name, $myText, into the poedit file itself. Of course, this is not optimal, but it could work.

What can't work, however, is when you have a foreach loop that spits out a php variable that could be defined hundreds of times. If you have:

```
<?php foreach($variables as $variable)
      {
          echo $variable;
      }
?>
```

and count($variables) > 100, or even 10, this workaround will be prohibitive. Is there a better way??

Comment: `"$var"` in PHP is synonymous with just `$var`, as long as `$var` is something that can be converted to a string. In other words, `_("$var")` sends the CONTENTS of the var into the function, not the name of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

`xgettext` (or `poedit`) is effectively a "static analyser", meaning, it doesn't run your code, it just finds all of the `_()` functions, and assumes that whatever is in it is a string to be translated.

So, if you do: `_('Hello, world')`
Then the string `Hello, world` will end up in your .po file.

If you do: `_("Hello, $planet")`
Then the string `Hello, $planet` will end up in your .po file.

This is often a good thing, since it allows us to remove (some) redundancy in your translation files. If we would have 3 planets, then we would need four translation strings; one for `hello, $planet`, and one for each planet.
If we would like to add `bye, $planet`, then we only need to add one extra translation string, and not 3.

Just wanted to make sure you understood that :-) Now, more specificity on the subject of your question:

> you would need to hardcode the variable name, $myText, into the poedit
>   file itself. Of course, this is not optimal, but it could work.

This won't work, since all `$myText` variables will resolve to the same translation string. I doubt that this is what you want?

Where are your variables coming from? If they're from a database or 3rd-party API you may want to look at a slightly different solution, such as scanning your database for translation strings, or fetching all strings from the 3rd-party API.
If you put those strings in your `.po` file, using `_($var)` will work fine, because the lookup itself is done at runtime.

Another possible solution is to make your own function, let's call it `v_()` (v for variable). At runtime, this function reads the contents of a `.po` file (or perhaps a database, which is later converted to a `.po` file), and if the string doesn't yet exists, it is inserted.

This might look something like this:

```
function v_($str) {
    global $translation_mode;

    if ($translation_mode && ! string_in_po_file($str))
        insert_string_in_po_file($str);

    return _($str);
}
```

Because this is executed at *run-time*, we know the contents of the string.
In this example we use a `$translation_mode` variable so this code has only minimal overhead on production machines.